# Solar Heat Gain/Outside Temperature Effects on a House

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, hvac

I'm currently a sophomore Mechanical engineering student and need some help with an equation for my project. I am coding a simulation in Matlab and have been given a very short time frame to do it. I chose to model the thermal efficiency of a house with the main output being cost to run heating/cooling system per day. Due to time constraints I tried to simplify the analysis a bit. I am neglecting heat transfer through siding, framing, the roof/ceiling, the floor, people inside, and appliances. Basically just four walls of insulation. I am looking at windows and solar heat gain from them. Since I am ignoring siding I am also ignoring solar heat gain transfer to it. Currently I have the program written to produce an output on a graph, but my equation to calculate the new inside temperature doesn't seem correct. I am using conduction through the insulation, convection from the ambient temperature inside, and solar heat gain due to the windows. I have restricted the size of the house to a 30'X40' single story with 8ft walls. The walls were also 1ft thick. So I ended up with the following:

Q_(conduction) + Q_(solar H.G. from windows) = Q_(convection due to ambient inside temp)
Where:

Q_(conduction) = -k*A*(T_wall-T_outside)/(Thickness of wall)
[A = total surface area of walls on house]

Q_(solar H.G. from windows) = (Area of window)*(Shading Coefficient)*(Solar Cooling Load Factor)

Q_(convection) = h*A*(T_wall-T_ambient)
[A = total surface area of walls on house]

From there I solved for the new temperature of the wall inside (T_wall). T_wall was used to show how the house's inside temperature changed from the desired inside temperature due to the outside temperature and solar heat gain. I'm currently finishing up my first thermodynamics class so this information is still relatively new to me. What information I could find for solar heat gain was from this website: [Solar Heat Gain](http://energy-models.com/heat-gains-and-losses-windows-and-skylights-glass)

Ten years of outside temperature data was pulled from the usclimatedata website. Does this equation look correct? Thanks in advance for any helpful advice/help!